# Load font for website for the whole session using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webfonts, google-font-api

I am making a website in hindi, for which i have to load font from google fonts using javascript.

I want to load the font for whole session only once on the start page, what javascript code should i use??

I use this code to load font on each page:

```
WebFontConfig = {
google: { families: [ 'Jaldi::devanagari' ] },
active: fontLoaded
};
(function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') + '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Browsers cache resources (unless caching has been disabled manually). That means, as long as the browser has the font in its font cache, adding the resource will *not* make the browser download the font again. It will instead use the font from the cache. (The same is true for JavaScript files, so the `webfont.js` script will also be cached).

Note however, that you still need to make the browser execute the script, so you need to add the `script` tag on every page where you need the font (as you are doing).

tl;dr: You don't need to change anything (as far as I can tell from your question at least).

Comment: actually i cover the page using a div until the fonts are loaded... i dont want it to appear on each page, but i want the font to be proper on each page... anyways thank you ;)